# DataSet generated by xsd.exe is not writing attributes on root element

Tags: c#, dataset, xsd.exe

Child elements of my data are being written directly off the root element instead of off the element that is their parent in the schema.

My xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="MyNameSpace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="MyNameSpace" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import/>
    <xs:element name="DataFile">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="LastUpdatedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="DateTimeLastUpdate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element name="DataValues" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="Num1" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="Num2" type="xs:int"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My input file:

```
<DataFile xmlns="MyNameSpace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="MyNameSpace MySchema.xsd">
    <LastUpdatedBy>Dan</LastUpdatedBy>
    <DateTimeLastUpdate>2009-12-07T16:40:30.0Z</DateTimeLastUpdate>
    <DataValues>
        <Num1>0</Num1>
        <Num2>0</Num2>
    </DataValues>
    <DataValues>
        <Num1>2</Num1>
        <Num2>0</Num2>
    </DataValues>
</DataFile>
```

What gets saved by `MyDataSet.WriteXml(filename)`

```
<DataFile xmlns="MyNameSpace">
    <LastUpdatedBy>Dan</LastUpdatedBy>
    <DateTimeLastUpdate>2009-12-07T16:40:30.0Z</DateTimeLastUpdate>
    <DataValues>
        <Num1>0</Num1>
        <Num2>0</Num2>
    </DataValues>
    <DataValues>
        <Num1>2</Num1>
        <Num2>0</Num2>
    </DataValues>
</DataFile>
```

The xmlns:xsi and xsi:schemaLocation attributes are not written.  What do I need to do to preserve them?

Answer (score 1):

What about `MyDataSet.WriteXml(filename, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);`

Although that will include the entire schema.

---

Looks like DataSet just doesn't support this. You have the NameSpace and Prefix properties to play with but that let's you only control 1 Namespace, and no xsi:schemaLocation.

Maybe [XmlDataDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument%28VS.100%29.aspx) could be useful? But note that it has been marked obsolete in Fx4

```
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(dataSet1);
```

Comment: That just changes what's wrong.  It loses the restrictions on the values of most elements in the schema (not shown above due to length).  It then creates a new top level element named after MyDataSet.DataSetName, that contains both the data and the mangled schema.  It then adds an element with all the attributes in the xsd except version, and three new ones:    xs:schema id="MyDataSet.DataSetName" xmlns:mstns="MyNameSpace" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"

Comment: At least by default that's doing the exact same thing as DataSet.WriteXml()

Comment: An XmlDocument gives you (greater) control over namespaces.

Comment: If I can't figure out how to make it write the files properly, I think I'm going to end up having to fall back on xml serialization for at least the lowest level file IO even if I immediately copy the date into datasets and leave it there until writing it out.